# Netbeans Run project button disabled

Tags: java, netbeans

I have been working on a project, everything was going smoothly and project has no errors. Last saved project was ok and running smoothly but when I opened same project after 2 days the run project button is disabled, no options are available/enable to run my project.

[image]

in above picture rectangle area in red color where options are disabled.
I dont know what should i do, I tried to copy same project and pasted in other location and opened from netbeans.. but still same problem.. How to run this project.. please any one help me out.. thanks

Comment: I am also searching for the solution. it happened with me a month ago.. but thank God, I used to backup at every stage of my project so.. I recovered from my last backup..

Comment: I dont have any backup.. what should i do now

Comment: Just some ideas: Have you selected a file? The buttons are for the active project. Can you build the project through the project context menu or shortcut?

Comment: Yes ... n all the options.. run, clean n build are disabled

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Disable "**Compile on Save**" and restart Netbeans.

Comment: this worked, but if i did not disable compile on save.. after few days.. it is good again.. i dont know why :p

Answer (score 16):

This problem happened to me several times before, I used to restart Netbeans and it works every time.

Answer (score 13):

Based on my experience, this happen when you close `Netbeans` while there are errors in the code and the **compile on save** option is working.

To solve this problem, just delete the folder **Build** from the directory of your project folder, and then start `Netbeans`.

Comment: This is the best answer as it also explains the reason.

Comment: This is the right answer. Disabling Compile on Save prevents this from happening again

Answer (score 2):

Put your mouse over project title, then you'll see the problem preventing project to run.

Answer (score 1):

Restart Netbeans, if still not solved then create a new folder and copy the content of the project to that newly created folder, then open that new folder project in Netbeans. That should work.

Comment: It is not optimal coding practice to dynamically disable a feature without offering explanations. Is there someone inside the NB community that could outline here what are the possible causes when a project is "greyed out"? Somewhere in the gui handling of NB, there must be a code snippet to investigate. This bug are many years old. Time to remove it?

It is very often sufficient to simply restart NB. This should be the first attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on project name in "Projects" tab and click on "Clean" menu item.
This works for me.

Comment: this prevents the need for restart...for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than one project you need to click on the project to select, then the Run button will be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

It happened to me when I did forget the square bracket after String statement.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfDVz.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30588355)

Comment: Community and Saman Salehi, sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 0):

My problem was caused by the fact the netbeans didnt know what the main project was.. Press the button named run (not the green run arrow), then set which one of your projects is the main one.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the NetBeans IDE, and it worked for me

Comment: Yes, Just told what I did last time. Same solution doesn't work always..

Answer (score 0):

In the project tab, you can `Right-click` on your project and click on `clean`.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by save project and restart Netbeans again

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).